# Discord.js - Making music bot speak to report actions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've had in mind to add a function to my music bot, so that, while it is playing music or videos in VC, it talks and reports if, for example, the song is looped, paused, stopped and others. I did find some codes for it but they would play **only** one of the two audios.

So what I would like to make, is making it play a local mp3 which says something like "Paused", "Stopped" and others, but over the music while it is playing. Is there a way to do it? Any help will be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found a solution, but instead of **Playing local .mp3 file** it will play a **Text to Speech** in the voice channel. Use the following with **discord.js v13.2.0**  :

1.npm i libsodium-wrappers

2.npm idiscordjs/voice

3.npm i discordjs/opus

4.npm i discord-tts

```js
const discordTTS=require("discord-tts");
const {Client, Intents} = require("discord.js");
const {AudioPlayer, createAudioResource, StreamType, entersState, VoiceConnectionStatus, joinVoiceChannel} = require("@discordjs/voice");

const token = '' //your token here
const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,]})

client.login(token);

client.on("ready", () => console.log("Online"));

let voiceConnection;
let audioPlayer=new AudioPlayer();

client.on("messageCreate", async (msg)=>{
    if(msg.content=="tts")
    {
        const stream=discordTTS.getVoiceStream("I am connected in the voice channel");
        const audioResource=createAudioResource(stream, {inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary, inlineVolume:true});
        if(!voiceConnection || voiceConnection?.status===VoiceConnectionStatus.Disconnected){
            voiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: msg.member.voice.channelId,
                guildId: msg.guildId,
                adapterCreator: msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });
            voiceConnection=await entersState(voiceConnection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Connecting, 5_000);
        }
        
        if(voiceConnection.status===VoiceConnectionStatus.Connected){
            voiceConnection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
            audioPlayer.play(audioResource);
        }
    }
});
client.login(token);
```

What you can do is, you can add various **tts** for events like **connected in vc**, **playing the song**, **song added to queue**.

For more information, you can [check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-tts) package.